# ffmpeg - embed metadata that updates regularly in video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, overlay, h.264

I have a video that was recorded with an ROV, or an underwater drone if you will. There video is stored in raw H.264, and lots of data is logged during a dive, like temperature, depth, pitch/roll/yaw, etc. Each log entry is timestamped with seconds since epoch.

Copying the raw H264 into an mp4 container at the correct framerate is easy, but I'd like to create a video that displays some or all of the metadata. I'd like to automate the process, so that I can come back from a trip and run a conversion batch tool that applies the metadata from new dives into the new video recordings. I'm hoping to avoid manual steps.

What are my options to display details on the video? Displaying text on the video is a common thing to do, but it isn't as clear to me how I could update it every few seconds based on an epoch timestamp from the logs. If I use -vf and try to use frame ranges for when to display each value, that'll be a very long filter. Would it help somehow if I generate an overlay video first? I don't see how that will be much easier, though.

Examples of some of the details I am hoping to embed are:

- depth
- temperature
- pitch, roll and yaw, perhaps by using "sprites" that can be rotated based on the logged rotation around each axis

Here's a small sample of some of the logged data:

```
1531168847.588000000 depth: 5.7318845
1531168848.229000000 attitude.calc.roll: -178.67145730705903
1531168848.229000000 attitude.calc.pitch: 8.89832326120461
1531168848.598000000 pressure.fluid_pressure_: 1598.800048828125
1531168848.898000000 temp.water.temperature.temperature_: 13.180000305175781
1531168849.229000000 attitude.calc.roll: -177.03372656909875
1531168849.229000000 attitude.calc.pitch: 3.697970708364904
1531168849.605000000 pressure.fluid_pressure_: 1594.0999755859375
1531168850.235000000 attitude.calc.yaw: 19.87041354690573
1531168850.666000000 pressure.fluid_pressure_: 1593.300048828125
```

The various values are logged at fairly irregular intervals, and they are not all updated at the same time.

I can massage the data into any necessary format. I also have a timestamp (epoch based) of when each recording started, so I can calculate approximate frame numbers as necessary. I have been searching for ways to apply the epoch timestamp to the video (PTS, RTCTIME/RTCSTART), without luck so far. If I manage that, I imagine use of the `enable` filter might be easier, but I'm still not sure very very long video filters are the way to go.

Comment: Very tedious, if not impossible, to do this with ffmpeg. You need a [telemetry](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/17727/1871) overlay app.

Comment: @Gyan Dashware looks like it does what I need. Unfortunately it seems to be Windows only. I'm running Ubuntu Linux, and I tried running it under Wine, but that didn't work. Interestingly, DashWare has both ffprobe.exe and ffmpeg.exe in the installed folder, so I guess it uses these somehow. I don't mean to underestimate the work they've put into developing DashWare, I just find it interesting that they appear to use ffmpeg.